# How to export all certifcates to file in Powershell

Tags: powershell, certificate

I am trying to export all my certificates but I am failing.

The closest solution I get, is this one:

```
$mypwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "secret" -Force -AsPlainText
Get-ChildItem -Path Cert: -Recurse | where { $_.Thumbprint} | Export-PfxCertificate -Cert $_.Thumbprint -Password $mypwd -FilePath $_.Thumbprint.pfx
```

But I get error

> Export-PfxCertificate : Das Argument kann nicht an den Parameter "Cert" gebunden werden, da es NULL ist.

Which means, $_ is NULL and cannot be used. I would expect the failed certificates are just skipped, but I don't get any single file exported.

Proposed solution does not work either:

```
PS D:\Temp> Get-ChildItem -Path Cert: -Recurse | where { $_.Thumbprint} | ForEach-Object {
    Export-PfxCertificate -Cert $_.Thumbprint -Password $mypwd -FilePath "$($_.Thumbprint).pfx"
}

Line |
   2 |      Export-PfxCertificate -Cert $_.Thumbprint -Password $mypwd -FileP …
     |      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Cannot find path 'C:\Users\Domscheit\2C85006A1A028BCC349DF23C474724C055FDE8B6' because it does not exist.
```

which sounds really strange, because it's the file to be exported.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ForEach-Object` to bind the current pipeline item to `$_`:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path Cert: -Recurse | where { $_.Thumbprint} | ForEach-Object {
    $_ |Export-PfxCertificate -Password $mypwd -FilePath "$($_.Thumbprint).pfx"
}
```

Comment: Does not work, please see my update.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Updated answer, try again

Comment: Getting better, however now error is "cannot export private Key".

Answer (score 0):

Which help from @Mathias R. Jessen I found a solution:

```
PS D:\Temp> Get-ChildItem -Path Cert: -Recurse | where { $_.Thumbprint} | ForEach-Object {
   Export-Certificate -Cert $_ -FilePath "$($_.Thumbprint).der" -Force
}
```

Using `Export-PfXCertificate` throws error "Cannot export private Key".
Default export format of `Export-PfXCertificate` is **DER**